# Get a tag that's inside a div with class

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="Checkbox">
  <img src='../tema/default/images/CheckVerde.png' onclick="Visibilidade('41767', 'img08ptNA_41767_0', '10')" style='cursor:pointer;margin: 4px;text-align:center;' ID='img08ptNA_41767_0' />
</div>
```

I need get the src value of the img tag, via jQuery.
The img ID is dynamic

How can I do that ?

Comment: When do you want to get the value of the `img` src? (on page load? on click?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(".Checkbox img").prop("src");`

Will work based on the provided html.  Of course, if you have multiple `div` elements or multiple images inside a div, you may have to use something like the `eq()` method for getting the value by index.

For example:

`$(".Checkbox:eq(0) img").prop("src");` - would get the first `div.Checkbox` image source.

Keep in mind that if there are multiple images inside of your selector, the `.prop()` methods only returns the value of the first one - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

`$('.Checkbox>img').prop('src');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.Checkbox').find('img').prop('src')
```

This can fetch the src attribute of all the img tags available in that class.